# How to resample a raster to higher resolution in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, r, modelling, resampling

I'm fitting a SDM using R. A requirement is that all environmental predictor layers have the same extent, origin and resolution.

I have high resolution bathymetry data (25m) that I will resample to 100m (precision of occurrence records). However, some environmental predictors pulled from a hydrodynamic model are at a much lower resolution (~7km) e.g. temperature / salinity.

I am aware of the introduction of error in resampling from low -> high resolutions. However, resampling the from 25m -> 7km is not suitable for my requirements.

Is it permissible, using QGIS, to define the resolution of the low resolution layers by saving the resolution to that of the higher res layers? Please note I am not resampling - just changing the number of columns & rows in the saved tiff so that R sees the layer as having an equal resolution to the other layers.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Some of our protocols take a little getting used to and you may have noticed that I removed your signature.  This is because every Question, Answer and Comment you post here is already signed by your [**user card**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/32203/user32203).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a more suitable solution: using the disaggregate function in R (raster package), achieve a resolution close to that you wish to resample to.  Then use the resample function (nearest neighbour) to get the exact resolution.

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you change the spatial resolution of a raster, you are resampling. If you want to keep exactly the same values as in the input data, you can use the "nearest neighbour" method.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with categorical data though I would avoid nearest neighbor resampling.

Comment: I agree. but the OP seems to have good reasons for not using another interpolation method.

Comment: Thanks for replies so far.  If changing the spatial resolution is resampling. Then which resampling method is used when simply defining a higher resolution for the tiff file while saving_as in a GIS? This resampling has zero processing time - or at least the same as saving to the native resolution?

Comment: Cubic resampling will most likely produce the best results for continuous data types.

Comment: Thank you @thehealingprocess... But perhaps I've not been as clear as I might. If I save a raster with a higher resolution than the native one, I (according to radouxju) have resampled as I have technically changed the spatial resolution. What I would like to know: 1. is this true resampling as there is no processing? 2. If not, then what is it? As using this method permits the raster to be used in R... Exactly what I want to do without resampling and introducing error.

Comment: there is a processing because each new pixel receives a value based on the larger pixel. This will be a nearest neighbour if yu do this.